# How to primary keys and clustering columns operate in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I'm confused as to how primary keys in Cassandra allow for quick data access. Say for example I create a table of Students with the following schema columns:

I choose the primary key to be Student Id. My understanding is that all the students will be placed around the cluster based on some hash of this value. Say I also choose the Country as a Clustering Column. So Within each partition of the students (who have been split based on their Id) they will be ordered by Country (presumably alphabetically).

So if I then want to retrieve all students for a specific country will I have to visit multiple nodes in the cluster? While the students have been ordered by Country within each node there is nothing to say that all the students for a specific country have been stored on the same node? Is this type of query even supported?

If I had only added 5 students to a 5 nodes cluster would it be possible that all the students would be stored on separate nodes if the Student Id was a UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I then want to retrieve all students for a specific country will I have to visit multiple nodes in the cluster?

Yes.

> While the students have been ordered by Country within each node there is nothing to say that all the students for a specific country have been stored on the same node?

Correct.

> Is this type of query even supported?

It is but that's considered an anti-pattern in Cassandra. What happens is that the coordinator (the node that receives the request from the client) will have to query ALL other nodes since it will have to scan all rows for that column family.

> If I had only added 5 students to a 5 nodes cluster would it be possible that all the students would be stored on separate nodes if the Student Id was a UUID?

Yes.

The way your problem can be solved is by having a column family for each query (one for selecting by Student ID and the other for selecting by Country, each one having a different primary query) while duplicating the rows (when you create a student you have to insert it in both column families).